# Find (Unix shell command) : how to use samefile operator with nonexistent files

Tags: unix, command-line, find

we have a script using find command like the following (delete old files except some special directory)

```
find /data/foo -mtime 30 -and -not -samefile /data/foo -and -not -samefile /data/foo/specialdir -delete
```

Now, the same script is used at multiple machines and some of those don't have that /data/foo/specialdir available. This results with error "find: /data/foo/specialdir: No such file or directory".

We can create that directory there but is there some other way to get "-not -samefile xyz" (or something similar) working if xyz doesn't exist?

br, Touko

EDIT: Had forgotten -delete at the end of the command at the original question

Answer (score 1):

You could make it in to a two-liner:

```
test -d /data/foo/specialdir || test_specialdir='-and -not -samefile /data/foo/specialdir'
find /data/foo -mtime 30 -and -not -samefile /data/foo "$test_specialdir"
```